# Pandas: Efficient way to get first row with element that is smaller than a given value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm wondering if there's an efficient way to do this in pandas: Given a dataframe, what is the first row that is smaller than a given value? For example, given:

```
      addr
0  4196656
1  4197034
2  4197075
3  4197082
4  4197134
```

What is the first value that is smaller than 4197080? I want it to return just the row with 4197075.
A solution would be to first filter by 4197080 and then take the last row, but that looks like to be an extremely slow O(N) operation (first building a dataframe and then taking its last row), while a binary search would take O(logN).

```
df.addr[ df.addr < 4197080].tail(1)
```

I timed it, and creating `df.addr[ df.addr < 4197080]` more or less takes the same as `df.addr[ df.addr < 4197080].tail(1)`, strongly hinting that internally it's building an entire df first.

```
num = np.random.randint(0, 10**8, 10**6)
num.sort()
df = pd.DataFrame({'addr':num})
df = df.set_index('addr', drop=False)
df = df.sort_index()
```

Getting the first smaller value is very slow:

```
%timeit df.addr[ df.addr < 57830391].tail(1)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.9 ms per loop
```

Using lt improves things a bit:

```
%timeit df.lt(57830391)[-1:]
1000 loops, best of 3: 853 µs per loop
```

But still nowhere near as fast as a binary search:

```
%timeit bisect(num, 57830391, 0, len(num))
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.53 µs per loop
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: using ``bisect`` seems pretty fast. so go with that. why does this time difference actually matter in practicality? are you doing this multiple times? (in which their ARE better ways). what is the actual problem you are solving?

Comment: FYI, sorting is by FAR the slowest operation here. you can try using ``nsmallest``, which DOES NOT sort. (new in 0.14.0)

Comment: But I'm only timing the queries, not the sort.. Yes, I'll be doing this query many times, could be thousands or millions of times. The actual problem is a bit complicated to explain here.. this is only part of the general algorithm.

Comment: Then see my answer. If you know its sorted, then its a pretty good query time.

Comment: and use ``searchsorted`` MUCH faster as ``bisect`` does operate on numpy arrays efficiently as ``searchsorted``.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This requires 0.14.0

Note that the frame IS NOT SORTED.

```
In [16]: s = df['addr']
```

Find biggest value lower than required

```
In [18]: %timeit s[s<5783091]
100 loops, best of 3: 9.01 ms per loop

In [19]: %timeit s[s<5783091].nlargest(1)
100 loops, best of 3: 11 ms per loop
```

So this is faster than actuallying performing a full-sort, then indexing.
The `.copy` is to avoid biasing the inplace sort.

```
In [32]: x = np.random.randint(0, 10**8, 10**6)

In [33]: def f(x):
   ....:     x.copy().sort()
   ....:     

In [35]: %timeit f(x)
10 loops, best of 3: 67.2 ms per loop
```

If you are simply searching an ALREADY SORTED series, then use `searchsorted`. Note that you must use the numpy version (e.g. operate on `.values`. The series version will be defined in 0.14.1)

```
In [41]: %timeit  s.values.searchsorted(5783091)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.5 µs per loop
```

Comment: Yes, bisect seems very fast, much faster than anything I can do in pandas. The question was whether I could make pandas just as fast.